# Typo3 - powermail - no emails are sent and no confirmation page

Tags: forms, email, typo3

I have the Typo3 powermail extension v2.0.6 and a form on this site: http://www.fg-energysolutions.de/kontakt.html

When sending the form, nothing happens at all. Neither Emails are sent to the receiver nor a confirmation to the sender. Also, no confirmation page is shown but it just loads the site with the form again.

I tried re-installing the powermail extension and re-created the form, but no effect. I also made sure that the PHP mail() function works. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Update: The issue is solved. I only know that the solution had something to do with configuration files such as the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check first, if the submitted fields are stored to the configured storage pid. If there aren't any entries in module powermail, something is wrong with storing to the database.

Did you install powermail via the extension mananger or programmatically in localconf.php? 
If you did programmatically, maybe you forgot to make the database updates in extension manager which creates the needed tables.

If there are entries, there's a problem with sending mails.
Try to send a testmail with TYPO3s Install Tool, maybe php mail works fine, but TYPO3 isn't allowed to do so (permissions?).

Maybe the typoscript configuration disables sending to sender like this?

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.sender.enable = 0  #change to 1 to enable!
```

Same for receiver.

Comment: The problem was solved by another way. However, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I created the contact form on an invisible copy of the actual contact page for testing purposes and the default "action" parameter was set to the URL of the original contact page, not the "index.php?id=xx" URL of the copy. Manually changing the "action" parameter to the URL of the correct (copy) page solved the problem for me.